# Epson Printer Expression HomeXP-305

Tags: printing, epson

I have tried many things with this new printer.  It installs in the `add printer` box.  When I ask it to print a test page the response is

```
idle - sending data to printer
```

and the job listing number just increases.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10. So far nothing has printed. I've been to the Epson download center and there is nothing suitable.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

Epson XP - 305

1. Install wine
2. Insert Epson CD and open folder
3. Open InstallNavi.exe with wine (right click on mouse > wine windows program loader)
4. Follow instructions from CD (when error appears do not close, but click show and continue application)
5. You should be able at one moment to have wi-fi connections full bars on the printer's LCD screen (follow instructions from the set up)
6. Open printers on upper right ubutu menu (shut down button near user account)
7. Click > Add printer....wait... after a while your printer shall appear
8. Choose and install driver (basically ubutu will do all the work)
9. Print test page
10. END

Comment: By which you mean to say "you must do the *initial* set up the printer using Windows"?

Answer (score 0):

InstallNavi.exe doesn't work with Wine.
There's a message telling "Sorry. Your OS (Ubuntu Linux) is not supported".
The first thing to do is uninstalling all previous printers in your system. Then Linux detectes your Epson printer with no problem.
The second thing is to go to "System Configuration">"Additional drivers", and download and activate Epson privative driver. Don't forget to restart your system after activating this driver.

With these previous two steps your printer will work properly.

I run an Epson XP-305 Multifunction on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

All fine.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is old i know but if someone need to know a way to setup a printer, here it is:

I just used the software "Printing". It comes with ubuntu and will find the driver automatically.

The printer XP-305 works just fine.

Give it a try.